# Realm: what is the defaultInstance if the app and one of it's libraries use Realm and set (both) the defaultConfiguration?

Tags: java, android, realm

Assume that we have an application that use Realm and one of it's libraries the app depends use Realm also (for it's own use).

How the Realm deals with the situation that the app and the library set (both) the Realm defaultConfiguration?
The defaultConfiguration is static variable and it's value is the same for the app and the library.

In addition, if the user choose database name that he never used, if the library have also the same database name, how the Realm deals with that (they both, the app and the library have the same Context.getLibFiles)?

Answer (score 1):

If the library and app both are both using `defaultConfiguration`, it depends on the timing of calling `getDefaultConfiguration()`. You can see from the source code:

```
public static void setDefaultConfiguration(RealmConfiguration configuration) {
    if (configuration == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A non-null RealmConfiguration must be provided");
    }
    defaultConfiguration = configuration;
}
```

It doesn't have any protection and checking when set it since it is designed to be called before user calling any `getDefaultRealm()` (or switching the default Realm).

IMO, lib should not set the default configuration at all. The default configuration should be controlled by the app itself.

Similar situation for the same Realm name problems for lib and app. Maybe you should consider to give the lib user a chance to set the Realm name or add domains to the lib's Realm to avoid collisions?